# How to make a vhdl Mealy state machine?

Tags: state, vhdl, fpga

"I'm programming a VHDL (modelsim) state machine (Mealy's machine)
I found this code on the internet but if I start it it gives me the following error, help me thanks in advance:"

```
** Error: D:/modelsim_ase/esercizi/prova.vhd(32): near "<=": (vcom-1576) expecting => or '|' or '!'.
** Error: D:/modelsim_ase/esercizi/prova.vhd(46): near "<=": (vcom-1576) expecting => or '|' or '!'.
** Error: D:/modelsim_ase/esercizi/FSM.vhd(85): VHDL Compiler exiting
```

line:

```vhdl
    when others => next_state <= (others <= 'x');
```

"the code is as follows:"

VHDL

```vhdl
-- Example of a 5-state Mealy FSM
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity mealy is
 port (clock, reset: in std_logic;
       data_out: out std_logic;
       data_in: in std_logic_vector (1 downto 0));
end mealy;
architecture behave of mealy is
 type state_values is (st0, st1, st2, st3, st4);
 signal pres_state, next_state: state_values;
begin
-- FSM register
statereg: process (clock, reset)
begin
 if (reset = '0') then
  pres_state <= st0;
  elsif (clock'event and clock ='1') then
    pres_state <= next_state;
  end if;
end process statereg;
-- FSM combinational block
fsm: process (pres_state, data_in)
begin
 case pres_state is
 when st0 =>
  case data_in is
   when "00" => next_state <= st0;
   when "01" => next_state <= st4;
   when "10" => next_state <= st1;
   when "11" => next_state <= st2;
   when others => next_state <= (others <= 'x');
  end case;
  when st1 =>
   case data_in is
    when "00" => next_state <= st0;
    when "10" => next_state <= st2;
    when others => next_state <= st1;
   end case;
  when st2 =>
   case data_in is
    when "00" => next_state <= st1;
    when "01" => next_state <= st1;
    when "10" => next_state <= st3;
    when "11" => next_state <= st3;
    when others => next_state <= (others <= 'x');
   end case;
  when st3 =>
   case data_in is
    when "01" => next_state <= st4;
    when "11" => next_state <= st4;
    when others => next_state <= st3;
   end case;
  when st4 =>
   case data_in is
    when "11" => next_state <= st4;
    when others => next_state <= st0;
   end case;
  when others => next_state <= st0;
 end case;
end process fsm;
-- Mealy output definition using pres_state w/ data_in
outputs: process (pres_state, data_in)
begin
 case pres_state is
  when st0 =>
   case data_in is
    when "00" => data_out <= '0';
    when others => data_out <= '1';
   end case;
  when st1 => data_out <= '0';
  when st2 =>
   case data_in is
    when "00" => data_out <= '0';
    when "01" => data_out <= '0';
    when others => data_out <= '1';
   end case;
  when st3 => data_out <= '1';
  when st4 =>
   case data_in is
    when "10" => data_out <= '1';
    when "11" => data_out <= '1';
    when others => data_out <= '0';
   end case;
  when others => data_out <= '0';
 end case;
end process outputs;
end behave;
```

Comment: Please paste your code here as text if you want comments

Comment: hi, I copied the code, there are also some images

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your code is full of transcription errors, for example the use « and » (which aren't ISO 9959-1 characters) instead of double quotation marks. There's a missing semicolon after the final end statement, there may be more. Your two errors can't be duplicated, instead there are many more. This example is found in the [Actel HDL Coding Style Guide](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_download/130823-hdl-coding-style-guide) Pages 39-40. This appears to have been copied from https://studfile.net/preview/4447484/page:5/

Comment: The typographic errors using of the compound delimiter "<=" instead of "=>" in the aggregate association lists are errors found in the original.

Comment: There are two additional typographic errors in the original, the use of the character literals 'x' in the same aggregate others choice should be 'X'. Character literals represent positional value of an enumeration type. 'x' is not an enumeration value of type std_ulogic declared in the std_logic_1164 package declaration.

Answer (score 0):

**The following from your code is an error**
You have transposed the "=>" symbol in the aggregate that contains only others:

```
when others => next_state <= (others <= 'x');
```

**The following is also an error since it is the wrong type for your example**
If it were appropriate to use an aggregate assignment here (it is not), the arrow should point in the opposite direction (=>) as shown below.  Also note that items in single quotes are case sensitive and that all std_ulogic/std_logic letters are upper case and hence it should be 'X' (also shown).

```
when others => next_state <= (others => 'X');
```

**You must do this to fix your code**
Since next_state has the type, state_values, it should instead be:

```
when others => next_state <= st0;
```

In addition, some of your other code is rendering funny, or you are using some of the languages alternative characters («00»).  Rather than this, I would recommend using "00" if your keyboard has the " character:

```
case data_in is
  when "00" => next_state <= st1;
```

Comment: You don't disclose the new problem. `(others => 'X')` is not a value of type `state_values`, an enumerated type with values  `st0`, `st1`, `st2`, `st3` and `st4`.  These are also errors found in the original code.  Fixing them is worthy of changing your question (and about now you might wish you had a valid example, Actel/Intel aside).